# How do I get a Sqlite Table attribute from a Class?

Tags: c#, sqlite, class, attributes

I would like to get a Sqlite `Table` attribute from my class.

I have a method to check if a table exists from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582180/how-to-check-table-exist-in-db-sqlite-xamarin-ios):

```
var info = database.Connection.GetTableInfo(typeof(Customer).Name);
if (info.Any())
{
    //do stuff with table
}
```

where `Customer` is:

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
  //class stuff
}
```

Now my method will work fine as it is but I would like to link it to the `Table` attribute rather than the class name incase I change the table name in future.

How do I go about getting my `Table` attribute from my class?

Ps. I am using a PCL (Portable Class Library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. Just needed to use the [GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) method on a `Type` and feed in the Attribute type I was looking for. So it became:

```
string tableName = typeof(Customer).Name;
var customAttributes = typeof(Customer).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SQLite.Net.Attributes.TableAttribute),false);
if (customAttributes.Count() > 0)
{
    tableName = (customAttributes.First() as SQLite.Net.Attributes.TableAttribute).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for a PCL:

```
using System.Reflection;

string tableName = typeof(MyClass).Name;
var customAttributes = typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes<SQLite.Net.Attributes.TableAttribute>();
if(customAttributes.Count() > 0)
{
    tableName = customAttributes.First().Name;
}
```

[Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18155/typeof-t-getcustomattribute-undefined-in-a-xamarin-forms-shared-project)